# Getting null value of the hidden field at server-side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am calling a Java-script function, in that i am passing the value of hidden field, that hidden field i want to use at server-side, but the value of hidden field is null.

**Client Side function**

```
function getDetails()
    {
        document.forms[0].HdnNode.value=tree_selected_id; //HTML Hidden Field.
        str="Cmp_12";
        str_array=str.split("_");
        var str_array1=str_array[0];
        var str_array2=str_array[1];
        document.getElementById("<%=HiddenNodeId.ClientId %>").value=str_array1;
        document.getElementById("<%=HiddenTreeId.ClientId %>").value=str_array2;                       
    }
```

**Server Side Function**

```
Public Sub InsertNodes(ByVal NodeId As String)
    Dim objErrorObj As New ErrorObj
    Dim ParentID As String
    ParentID = HiddenNodeParent.Value
    NodeId = HiddenNodeId.Value
    Dim NodeIDTree As String
    NodeIDTree = HiddenTreeId.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you format your code using the code block? Also, have you tried alerting the hidden field value before sending it to the server? Might help you in figuring out whether it's a client side or server side issue

Comment: what is the html code? Probably you do not call correctly the getDetails, or you have a javascript error.

Comment: @Peter I am using asp controls
 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenNodeId" runat="server" />
 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenNodeParent" runat="server" />

Comment: In your "getDetails" function, try just setting the values of the hidden fields to a "test" value, with nothing else in the function. Your code might be bombing out on the first line of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I am using hidden fields with UpdatePanels  ( hidden field must be send back to server to use it in partial postback  ) and you can try set EnableViewState = true ( whole page post back ).

aspx:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="LinesBack" value="0"/>

       <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="10" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <img id="spinner" alt="spinner" src="../Pictures/spinner_30x30.gif" />
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
            <div id="Back" class="NewresultPanel" runat="server" ></div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

html:

```
var a = document.getElementById('<%= LinesBack.ClientID %>').value;
```

cs:

```
            LinesBack.Value = CountRows.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `runat="server"` attribute for the hidden field to access it in server side code that you have posted.

Something like

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidTest" runat="server" />
```

server side code

```
hidTest.Value;
```

Comment: I using asp hiddenfield.
 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenNodeId" runat="server" />
 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenNodeParent" runat="server" />

Comment: I had converted all asp control into html control but still the hidden field value is null.